# asp.net cookieless for certain pages on site

Tags: asp.net, cookies, session-cookies, cookieless

To avoid adding cookie consent acceptance, I would like to disable cookies for certain pages in my asp.net site. I know I can add this to the config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState cookieless="true" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But is it possible to specify that only certain pages (in matter fact only one page) to be cookieless?